# Why is groovy changing the hours/minutes after parsing and formatting date string?

Tags: java, groovy, simpledateformat, katalon-studio

I'm pulling a date string from a SQL table. The date string being pulled from Sql is...

`2020-07-28 15:35:45.9375232 -05:00`

and when I try and parse and format, it's returning a different time than what was passed in.

Method1:

```
String record = data.getValue(4, 1) 
// returns "2020-07-28 15:43:16.5168174 -05:00" from SQL table
    
def formattedDate = Date.parse("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSS XXX", record).format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS")
        log.logInfo("queried date = " + formattedDate)
```

Returns `2020-07-28T17:09:24.174`

and Method2:

```
def queriedDate2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSS XXX").parse(record)
    log.logInfo("queriedDate2= " + queriedDate2)
```

Returns `Tue Jul 28 17:09:24 CDT 2020`

Can anyone help me understand what's going on?

Comment: Changing the minutes from 43 to 9 is difficult to explain. Are you sure the time strings you gave are correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably `SimpleDateFormat` is ignoring the zone-offset (-5 hours) in the give date-time string and applying your JVM's time-zone while parsing it. I suggest you switch from the outdated and error-prone `java.util.Date` and `SimpleDateFormat` to the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html) to get rid of such problems.

```
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Given date-time string
        String dateTimeStr = "2020-07-28 15:35:45.9375232 -05:00";

        // OffsetDateTime from the given date-time string
        OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse(dateTimeStr,
                DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSS XXX"));
        System.out.println(odt);

        // You can print it in different forms using DateTimeFormatter patterns e.g.
        System.out.println(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM dd uuuu").format(odt));
        System.out.println(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM dd uuuu HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSS ZZZZZ").format(odt));
        System.out.println(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/uuuu/dd hh:mm:ss a").format(odt));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-07-28T15:35:45.937523200-05:00
Jul 28 2020
Jul 28 2020 15:35:45.9375232 -05:00
07/2020/28 03:35:45 pm
```

Comment: You didn't answer his question.

Comment: @ou_ryperd - One of the most important aspects of SO is building a knowledge repository and sometimes a direct solution to the problem may not be the outcome of an answer. You will find [Hovercraft Full Of Eels](https://stackoverflow.com/users/522444/hovercraft-full-of-eels) quoting this at multiple places. The way I've put the answer clearly points to the fact that there may be some problems due to the way `java.util.Date` and `SimpleDateFormat` work. Instead of wasting time to find that, I've suggested OP to switch to `OffsetDateTime`. I do not know what prompted you to downvote this answer.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it wasn't me who downvoted you, in fact I referred to your answer as the correct solution in my answer. I commented because OP literally ended his question with "Can anyone help me understand what's going on?" and you didn't answer that. No harm done.

Comment: @ou_ryperd - Thank you. I hadn't gone through your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your

```
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSS XXX")
```

expects a timezone, e.g. GMT for the XXX. Your returned value

```
"2020-07-28 15:43:16.5168174 -05:00"
```

seems to have a GMT offset: `-05:00`
I would guess that the .parse() is erroneous and returns some sort of default format.

Because of that, it is suggested to use Arvind's suggested OffsetDateTime.